# How to use mapStateToProps to get a value from the state based on a context value?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I've an application when most of the data are stored in the store but the selected item is provided thought the usage of a React.Context.

React-Redux provide the `connect` api that accept a `mapStateToProps` function with `state` and `props` as a component.

What I would like, if it didn't break the hooks, is something like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  const selectedItemId = useContext(MySelectedItemContext)
  return {
    item: state.items[selectedItemId]
  }
}
```

but of course it is not possible since I'm outside of the component and cannot invoke the useContext.

So, I tried to use the old API context:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props){
  return {
    item: state.items[props.id]
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)((props) =>
  <MySelectedItemContext.Consumer>
  { selectedItemId => <Component id={selectedItemId} {...props}/> }
  </MySelectedItemContext.Consumer>)
```

but this still not works because the connect returns a new component that has the consumer inside instead of outside and id prop is not defined yet in mapStateToProps.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to remove `mapStateToProps` and use `useSelector` hooks and Redux selectors. But if you need `mapStateToProps`, then you can wrap your component that must be connected to Redux into another component that will get value from context and will pass it to a component that uses Redux.

```
// Use this component
export function ContextConsumerComponent() {
  const selectedItemId = useContext(SelectedItemIdContext);

  return <ReduxConsumerComponent id={selectedItemId} />;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    item: state.items[props.id]
  }
}

const ReduxConsumerComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)((props) => {
  // props.item will be here
});
```